# cygwin ssh gives "Killed by signal 1" on exit

Tags: bash, ssh, cygwin, signals

After using cygwin's ssh to login from windows to linux-hosts, 
when exiting the remote shell, I always get the annoying msg:

"Killed by signal 1"

I googled, and realize its harmless, but still annoying...
Some suggested you can get rid of the message by using

$ ssh -q ...

But that has no effect on any of the machines I've tried.

Anyone knows a working solution to get rid of this msg?

Comment: Nope. Still getting that msg.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding following line to your `~/.ssh/config` file can squash that message.

**Update: QUIET must be all CAPS & must added for each host in your config.**

```
LogLevel QUIET
```

Added in first line will squash the message globally. Will only take effect for the specific hosts if it's placed under `Host`.

Comment: More detail here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client

Answer (score 46):

This happens when you proxy your ssh session through another host. Example `.ssh/config` file:

```
# machine with open SSH port
Host proxy
HostName foo.com

# machine accessible only from the above machine
Host target
HostName 192.168.0.12
ProxyCommand ssh proxy nc %h %p
```

When you exit from an `ssh target`, the `ssh` in `ProxyCommand` will cause the output. If you add the `-q` there, it will be suppressed:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -q proxy nc %h %p
```

You may be surprised that this output has nothing to do with Cygwin -- it happens on Linux as well.

Comment: One one of my older SunOS still-in-production boxes, `OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8b 04 May 2006` doesn't support this option. Also, `-W` has nothing to do with the original problem.

Answer (score 6):

*I'm adding a new answer because I have a new solution under different circumstances.*

When using the modern `ProxyJump` directive, there is no place to put the `-q`, as with `ProxyCommand`:

```
Host target
  ProxyJump proxy
```

Instead of switching back to the more manual jump definition with `ProxyCommand`, the solution with `ProxyJump` is to add `LogLevel QUIET` to a `Host proxy` definition:

```
Host target
  ProxyJump proxy
Host proxy
  LogLevel QUIET
```

which will have the same effect as the `-q` in `ProxyCommand`'s `ssh -q proxy ...`.

Answer (score 3):

In a script bash, to get rid of this message, add the following at the top:

```
exec 2> >(grep -v "Killed by signal 1.")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enable connection sharing with the ControlMaster directive you can share a single connection when proxying sessions through another host.  You can then set the ControlPersist directive to 1 second which will avoid the 'killed by signal 1' error by delaying the termination of the shared connection.

Add the following to your ~/.ssh/config

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist 1
ControlPath ~/.ssh/.%C
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you might like [PuTTY](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/putty_portable) as an alternative. I don't think it gives that error AND it allows you to do things like save connection info as well as other niceties.

Though I haven't tried it, you might also be able to redirect sterr (which is the stream I believe that message would be sent to) to /dev/null (effectively, the bitbucket or bottomless void where things go to die). You could do possibly do something like:

ssh user@host 2>/dev/null