# Perl SSH error - Killed by signal 1

Tags: perl, ssh

I my trying to connect via SSH, and getting error message "Killed by signal 1."

This is my code.

```
use CGI;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $machineCon = 'my-server';
my $username = 'my-username';
my $password = 'my-password';

$ssh_obj = Net::OpenSSH->new(
    $machineCon,
    strict_mode => 0,
    master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"],
    ctl_dir => "/tmp/",
    timeout => 200,
    strict_mode => 0,
    user     => $username,
    password => $password,
    ssh_cmd => '/usr/bin/ssh'
);

if( !$ssh_obj->error )
{
    # Is my process running?
    my $PROC = $ssh_obj->capture( "pwd" );
    print $PROC;
}
else
{
     print $ssh_obj->error
}
```

I have looked many comments, but it is not help me.
Any advice.
Thanks

Comment: Try add `use strict; use warnings;`. Make sure there are no warnings.

Comment: It could also be that your code works just fine. According to [cygwin ssh gives “Killed by signal 1” on exit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12639615/2173773) it could be some kind of residual output when using a proxy command. This message could then safely be ignored or even silenced (see the link).

Answer (score 1):

You should add this option in your new() method call.

```
kill_ssh_on_timeout => 0
```

If your code doesn't timeout now, then you know there is a connectivity issue.

And for more help, just add this line to see all errors:

```
$Net::OpenSSH::debug = ~0;
```